# Show all calls from method to other methods

Tags: java, aspectj

Let's say I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    calculate();
}

public void calculate() {
    int n1 = 100;
    int n2 = 100;

    add(n1, n2);
}

public int add(int n1, int n2) {
    int result = n1 + n2;
    return result;
}
```

My goal is to display all subcalls from the methods in this program.

So when i execute calculate() the result must be printed out like this:

```
calculate()
    -> add(int, int)
```

Any idea how to do this? I heard that I can use cflow but i have no idea how.

Comment: Can't you just print the name of the function inside the function itself?

Comment: I found the answer to my problem here. 
http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/examples-development.html#tracing-using-aspects

Basically, I used a callDepth variable to calculate the number of tabs. When entering a method (using before) I incremented the callDepth and decremented it when leaving (after).

Answer (score 0):

I would say one way would be to use StackTraceElement, specifically getMethodName(). This site has a tutorial on how to use this method: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stacktraceelement_getmethodname.htm